# zsh basename and ${var%.*}

Tags: shell, zsh

How to understand the different output between file2 and file3?

```
(base) ➜  Youtube cat 1.sh
base="/VS/Harry Potter - Hedwig's Theme (Harmonica Ver.) [w2kuM-Rp_IY].info.json"
echo "base:  $base";
dir=$(dirname "$base");
filename=$(basename "$base");
file=${${filename%.*}%.*};
file2=${${"$(basename $filename)"%.*}%.*};
file3=${${$(basename $filename)%.*}%.*};
echo "file:  $dir/$file";
echo "file2: $dir/$file2";
echo "file3: $dir/$file3";

(base) ➜  Youtube zsh 1.sh
base:  /VS/Harry Potter - Hedwig's Theme (Harmonica Ver.) [w2kuM-Rp_IY].info.json
file:  /VS/Harry Potter - Hedwig's Theme (Harmonica Ver.) [w2kuM-Rp_IY]
file2: /VS/Harry Potter - Hedwig's Theme (Harmonica Ver.) [w2kuM-Rp_IY]
file3: /VS/Harry Potter - Hedwig's Theme (Harmonica Ver [w2kuM-Rp_IY]
```

It seems basename command returns a serval part split by space and `${var%.*}` command works on each part.

Comment: FYI: You can write `dir=$base:h` and `filename=$base:t` which saves 2 child processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems basename command returns a serval part split by space and `${var%.*}` command works on each part.

Pretty much, yes.

From [the documentation on command substitution](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Command-Substitution):

> If the substitution is not enclosed in double quotes, the output is broken into words using the `IFS` parameter.

And from the section on [parameter expansion](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion) talking about pattern deletion and substitutions:

> ... when *name* is an array and the substitution is not quoted, or if the `(@)` flag or the `name[@]` syntax is used, **matching and replacement is performed on each array element separately**.

So that's the situation you're running into with the unquoted command substitution. Its output is broken up into words and each word is checked for a matching pattern to delete.

Comment: The situation I encountered is fully explained by what you write above.
You are so kind to list the url link on the subject and I have learnt a lot from the url link.
Thank you and have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't quote the `$( command substitution )` so it got split by `IFS` characters and treated like an array value by subsequent nested `${}` parameter expansions. Being array valued, the `${param%pattern}` expansion was applied to each element. Then the result was joined by the first character of `IFS` due to `file3=...` being a scalar assignment. This would have happened to the output from any command - it is not specific to `basename`. The effect would have been more noticeable had the input string contained >1 type of IFS character or >1 sequential IFS character.

In zsh you may use the `t` (tail) or `h` (head) expansion modifiers, rather than external `basename` or `dirname` tools.

The `r` (root) modifier seems to be a better fit for your use case of chomping off the "extension" part:

```
base="/VS/Harry Potter - Hedwig's Theme (Harmonica Ver.) [w2kuM-Rp_IY].info.json"
file4=$base:r:r
typeset -p file4
```

It will only act on the tail of the path, so you don't need to do your own split->modify->join processing. `file4=$base:F[2]r` is another option instead of doubling the `:r`. That is the `F:expr:` modifier to repeat the following `r` modifier 2 times.

Comment: I mostly used ksh and bash years ago, and it's a big time for me today after starting to use zsh. 
The command you mentioned is so helpful.
Thanks a lot.